# how to select only integer values of a column

Tags: r

my data have many columns with different names and want see all numeric values only in column `name_id` and store those values in z. 
I want `z` should contains only numeric values of column `name_id` of `data`, if any alphabet is there in column then it should not get store in `z`.

```
z <- unique(data$name_id)
z
#[1] 10 11 12 13 14 3  4  5  6  7  8  9 
#Levels: 10 11 12 13 14 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f
```

when i tried this

```
z <-  unique(as.numeric(data$name_id))
z
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
```

output contains values only till 12 but column has values greater than 12 also

Comment: @Dave2e column have both datatype integer as well as character, i want to select integer values only and store those integer values in z.

Comment: You need `as.numeric(as.character(`

Answer (score 0):

Considering your data frame as

```
> b
 [1] "1"    "2"    "3"    "4"    "5"    "13"   "14"   "15"   "45"   "567"  "999"  "Name" "Age"
```

Apply this :

```
regexp <- "[[:digit:]]+"
> z <- str_extract(b , regexp)
z[is.na(z)] <- ""

> z
 [1] "1"   "2"   "3"   "4"   "5"   "13"  "14"  "15"  "45"  "567" "999" ""    ""
```

Hope this helps .

Comment: it will store values only from 0 to 9..what about values greater then 9?

Comment: Please see the edited answer .

Comment: want to do in a simple way..look at edited question again..

Comment: you can get the same results for all values , even for values greater than 12 or any other number. Try once .